# The number of isolated points in a compact space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact  topological space( it is Hausdorff). Can $X$ have infinitely many isolated points?

Comment: $\{0, 1, 1/2, 1/3,\ldots\}$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.

Comment: Don't forget: On the real line, closed and bounded sets are compact. All you need to do is take infinitely many isolated points inside a bounded interval, then you are done. The examples given here will illustrate this principle of construction.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Take $X=\{0\}\cup\{2^{-n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ with the topology given by the distance $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Then $X$ is compact (it is bounded and closed) and it contains infinitely many isolated points, namely $\{2^{-n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

It can have as many isolated points as you want. Let $Y$ be an arbitrary infinite set, let $p$ be any point not in $Y$, let $X=\{p\}\cup Y$, and let

$$\tau=\wp(Y)\cup\{X\setminus F:F\text{ is a finite subset of }Y\}\;.$$

$\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is easily seen to be a Hausdorff space in which each point of $Y$ is isolated, and it is also compact: if $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is some $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $p\in U$, and the finite set $X\setminus U$ can clearly be covered by just finitely many members of $\mathscr{U}$. (In fact $X$ is just the one-point compactification of its subspace $Y$, which has the discrete topology.)

**Robert Z**’s answer is a specific instance of this construction for countably infinite $Y$.